# SQL Query - How to get count where current row values in between previous rows

Tags: sql, count

So, I have to calculate total `Type` A where `From` & `To` in between `From` & `To` `Type` B based on `ID`.
I can't describe it in good words, so this is the example and my expected result (Column `Count`) :

```
ID  | Type | From | To | Count
-------------------------------
100 | A    | 10   | 14 | 
100 | A    | 16   | 18 | 
100 | B    | 12   | 14 | 1
100 | B    | 11   | 13 | 1
100 | B    | 17   | 18 | 1
120 | A    | 5    | 10 | 
120 | A    | 12   | 14 | 
120 | A    | 18   | 20 | 
120 | A    | 18   | 20 | 
120 | A    | 22   | 24 | 
120 | B    | 30   | 32 | 0
120 | B    | 19   | 20 | 2
120 | B    | 10   | 14 | 1
```

Anybody can help ? I'm expecting something similar like COUNT OVER or RANK OVER without GROUP BY because the table above is not original table, its from another subquery..

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . . I think a correlated subquery does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when type = 'B'
             then (select count(*)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.type = 'A' and
                         t2.from >= t.to and
                         t2.to <= t.from
                  )
        end) as count
from t;
```

I'm not sure if the logic for `between` includes the endpoints.  Traditionally, in SQL, it does.  But if that is not your intention, then you may need `<` or `>`.